# How to disable color interpolation in opengl es 2.0?

Tags: android, shader, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

Since there is no option for flat shading in opengl es is there a workaround to disable the color interpolation when different color is being passed to each of the vertices?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I'm sorry IYoung are you looking a solution for this yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the only way to do it is to draw using triangles, not triangle strips nor fans. And for each set of three vertices to makeup individual triangles use the same color. That'll remove the shading effect cause interpolating between the same color is the same color.
More complicated explanation: http://ruh.li/GraphicsShading.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not.

If you need flat-shaded faces in ES 2.0, the only way to do it is to make duplicates of all the vertices so that each face has three unique vertices, and populate those vertices with the per-face attributes.

Comment: Thats pain in the ass, I hope they change it soon.